# TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable on if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am tring to verify if a global variable exist or not.

```
def add_users():
    global users
    users = []
    while True:
        if 'STATUS' not in globals:
            server.listen()
            client, client_addr = server.accept()
            print(colored(f'[+] {client_addr} Client connected to the server', 'yellow'))
            users.append([client, client_addr])
```

i know the variable doesn't exist it's exactly what i want, The condition is verified ? why am i having this error?

error : `if 'STATUS' not in globals:` `TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable`

Comment: You need to call it... `globals()`... it's a function that returns the global dictionary...

Comment: You almost never want to touch it though... so you might want to rethink your logic and not use it

Answer (score 0):

`globals` is not a dictionary containing your global variables, it's a function that returns that dictionary. So you would have to call it to check whether `'STATUS'` is in there:

```py
def add_users():
    global users
    users = []
    while True:
        if 'STATUS' not in globals():
            server.listen()
            client, client_addr = server.accept()
            print(colored(f'[+] {client_addr} Client connected to the server', 'yellow'))
            users.append([client, client_addr])
```